# Watchguard XTM blocking login attempts

Tags: watchguard

routinely I'm seeing lots of login attempts to my mail server trying out various login names starting from A to Z coming from the one IP on one day and another IP on another day.  Is there any means to detect this type of activities and block accordingly?  I asked Watchguard and it appears they don't support this on their XTM series.  Anything else I can do other than to have a super long password?

Comment: Are the IP addresses in the same subnet ? Can you limit the number of login attempts ?

Comment: @Vinz No it comes from a variety of IPs.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical example of the "background noise" you'll find on most servers exposed to the internet.

A common solution is to have a script parse your log files to find those repeat offenders and then block the originating ip-adresses in the servers local firewall.

`fail2ban` is one such example.

Comment: Is there a way to block it on the network device level with any UTM devices?  I'd tend to think the XTM series would do such thing but apparently not.

Comment: I have no experience with Watchguard products, so I can't help you there. I imagine it also strongly depends on the protocol, a clear text protocol would allow an intrusion detection/prevention appliance easily tally incorrect username/password messages and take action. If the protocol/connection is SSL/TLS encrypted the appliance would need a copy of the private key and actively decrypt all traffic, which I would expect to come at an performance and price premium.  Depending on the number and skill level of your legitimate users you could move services to non-default ports.